# Razer DeathAdder mouse going nuts

Tags: hardware, mouse

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 and a Razer DeathAdder mouse. I've used the mouse in other distros perfectly but now it happens that randomly after some time it will start to act buggy and click things by itself, I have to unplug it and plug it back. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I had this too with my DeathAdder, I believe I looked it up and it was actually the mouse itself giving up after some time. I ended up buying a €20 mouse that worked ever since.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem with my mouse randomly clicking things.  But I have had similar problems with scrolling.  So it sounds like unplugging and plugging it back in is a very common fix.  It sounds like a common bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a driver issue, I have similar problems with my Cyborg R.A.T. I am not familiar with your mouse, but you might want to check the manufacturer's website (or Google) for Ubuntu drivers.